# Relate event registrations with contract roles

Tags: related-list

I am a little new into the SF ecosystem so apologies if I am asking something very simple. I am trying to show as a related list under the event registration object, all the contract roles a contact might have. So once a user is viewing a contact's registration to show on the side the contact's contract roles. Do I need to create a junction object?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
Eleni.

[image: Schema]

Comment: Are you trying to add this related list to the `Contact`, or to the `Event Registration`? If it's the latter, then what you're trying to do isn't possible as-is. You can only add a related list to the page layout for the "parent" SObject when it has a direct relationship to the "child" SObject (`Contact` is a "parent", `ContactRole` is a "child". The SObjects with the "crow's foot" in that diagram are "child" objects)

Comment: Edit was made around the same time as my comment. Yes, if this is possible, you'll need a junction object between `EventRegistration` and `ContractRole`. A trigger (or a flow) would be needed to insert/manage the records of that junction object.

Comment: Thank you Derek. Yes it is the latter. Perfect then I will give this a try :).

Thank you,
Eleni.